# How can I count rows in this sql statement?

Tags: sql, zend-framework, count

Could you help me by answering the following question?
How can I count rows in this sql statement?

```
SELECT `u`.*, 
   ( 6371 * Acos(Cos(Radians(51.6992)) * Cos(Radians(localization_lat)) * 
                               Cos(Radians(localization_lng) - Radians( 
                                   5.3042)) + 
                 Sin 
                   ( 
                          Radians(51.6992)) * Sin(Radians(localization_lat)) 
            ) ) AS 
   `distance` 
FROM   `ads` AS `u` 
WHERE  ( localization_zip_code LIKE '%5200%' ) 
       AND ( date_end > '2016-03-19 19:34:43' 
             AND date_start < '2016-03-19 19:34:43' ) 
       AND ( is_show = 1 ) 
       AND ( is_accept_admin = 1 ) 
       AND ( is_in_category_page = 1 ) 
HAVING ( `distance` < '70' ) 
ORDER  BY `distance` ASC
```

Comment: Mysql `count()`.  `SELECT COUNT(column) FROM ...`.  It would be easier to provide a more complete answer if you provided your current and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

`select count(*) from table` or `select count(column name) from table` method returns the number of records
try

```
SELECT Count(*), 
   `u`.*, 
   ( 6371 * Acos(Cos(Radians(51.6992)) * Cos(Radians(localization_lat)) * 
                               Cos(Radians(localization_lng) - Radians( 
                                   5.3042)) + 
                 Sin 
                   ( 
                          Radians(51.6992)) * Sin(Radians(localization_lat)) 
            ) ) AS 
   `distance` 
FROM   `ads` AS `u` 
WHERE  ( localization_zip_code LIKE '%5200%' ) 
       AND ( date_end > '2016-03-19 19:34:43' 
             AND date_start < '2016-03-19 19:34:43' ) 
       AND ( is_show = 1 ) 
       AND ( is_accept_admin = 1 ) 
       AND ( is_in_category_page = 1 ) 
HAVING ( `distance` < '70' ) 
ORDER  BY `distance` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know, but when I put count() in the statement I get 0 resulsts whilst without count() I get two in this case...
Can I use count() and HAVING in one sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it as a subquery `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...) AS mysubquery`.  So maybe something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT `u`.*,
     ( 6371 * Acos(Cos(Radians(51.6992)) * Cos(Radians(localization_lat)) *
                                 Cos(Radians(localization_lng) - Radians(
                                     5.3042)) +
                   Sin
                     (
                            Radians(51.6992)) * Sin(Radians(localization_lat))
              ) ) AS
     `distance`
  FROM   `ads` AS `u`
  WHERE  ( localization_zip_code LIKE '%5200%' )
         AND ( date_end > '2016-03-19 19:34:43'
               AND date_start < '2016-03-19 19:34:43' )
         AND ( is_show = 1 )
         AND ( is_accept_admin = 1 )
         AND ( is_in_category_page = 1 )
  HAVING ( `distance` < '70' )
  ORDER  BY `distance` ASC
  ) AS mysubquery
```